# react-router doesn't send me to the right component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

when i try to go to "shop/checkout/" i get the "/:current/:project" (i get ProjectPage and not CheckoutPage)
what am I doing wrong?
the "/:current" is coming from the design component.

```
      <Switch location={location}>
      <Route exact path="/design" component={Design} />
      <Route exact path="/shop" component={Shop} />
      <Route exact path="/:current/:project" component={ProjectPage}/>
      <Route exact path="/shop/checkout" component={CheckoutPage}/>
      </Switch>

      design page:
      <Link to={`${useLocation().pathname}/${title}`} />
      //useLocation = "/design", ${title} is a project name, im maping through projects and when the user click a project it uses the name of the project to the url

      shop:
      <Link to="/shop/checkout">CHECKOUT</Link>
```

Comment: Doesn't the literal route need to go before the variable route? Otherwise, `shop` and `checkout` could be read as parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because shop and checkout are read as parameters. Then it renders the ProjectPage component.

Just put the `/shop/checkout` route before your dynamic route with parameters.

```
<Switch location={location}>
  <Route exact path="/design" component={Design} />
  <Route exact path="/shop" component={Shop} />
  <Route exact path="/shop/checkout" component={CheckoutPage}/>
  <Route exact path="/:current/:project" component={ProjectPage}/>
 </Switch>
```